# Add section attribute to global variable in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

```
int x `__attribute__ ((section("some_name")))`;
```

I have a global variable **`x`** and would like to add `__attribute__ ((section("custom_name")))` to it. How would i do that in LLVM?

I created the global variable `x` as below.

```
GlobalVariable *x =
        new GlobalVariable(M, Type::getInt32Ty(C), false, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 0,
                           "x");
```

Comment: I didn't try this one, but maybe `void addAttribute(StringRef Kind, StringRef Val = StringRef())` will do the job?

Comment: Use `void GlobalObject::setSection(StringRef S) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
[void GlobalObject::setSection(StringRef S)](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html#a959c99adbdc7f8375cf866916c6b60f2)

 method from parent class GlobalObject.

```
GlobalVariable *x = new GlobalVariable(...);

x->setSection(".lrodata") // >2GB rodata on Linux x86_64
x->setAlignment(llvm::Align(N));
```